# reshape dataframe from column to rows in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pivot, apache-spark-sql

I want to reshape a dataframe in Spark using scala . I found most of the example uses `groupBy` and`pivot`. In my case i dont want to use groupBy. This is how my dataframe looks like

```
  tagid           timestamp value
1     1 2016-12-01 05:30:00     5
2     1 2017-12-01 05:31:00     6
3     1 2017-11-01 05:32:00     4
4     1 2017-11-01 05:33:00     5
5     2 2016-12-01 05:30:00   100
6     2 2017-12-01 05:31:00   111
7     2 2017-11-01 05:32:00   109
8     2 2016-12-01 05:34:00    95
```

And i want my dataframe to look like this,

```
            timestamp  1  2 
1 2016-12-01 05:30:00  5 100
2 2017-12-01 05:31:00  6 111
3 2017-11-01 05:32:00  4 109
4 2017-11-01 05:33:00  5  NA
5 2016-12-01 05:34:00 NA  95
```

i used pivot without groupBy and it throws error.

```
df.pivot("tagid")
```

> error: value pivot is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.

How do i convert this? Thank you.

Comment: `pivot` requires [RelationalGroupedDataset](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset) and hence `groupBy`. It's to say you've got no choice but `groupBy` **before** `pivot`.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any other approach to reshape the dataframe, other than pivoting method? Actually groupBy and pivot worked fine for me. But i still would like to know any other approaches are possible

Comment: I don't think so. The problem looks as a good match for `pivot` (and so `groupBy`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the following should solve your issue.

```
df.groupBy("timestamp").pivot("tagId").agg(first($"value"))
```

you should have final dataframe as

```
+-------------------+----+----+
|timestamp          |1   |2   |
+-------------------+----+----+
|2017-11-01 05:33:00|5   |null|
|2017-11-01 05:32:00|4   |109 |
|2017-12-01 05:31:00|6   |111 |
|2016-12-01 05:30:00|5   |100 |
|2016-12-01 05:34:00|null|95  |
+-------------------+----+----+
```

for more information you can checkout [databricks blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html)

Comment: Interesting since the solution is against... _"In my case i dont want to use groupBy."_ :)